# ASP.Net Dynamic Data - Can you intercept the save?

Tags: dynamic-data

We're looking at building an app with dynamic data.  What we'd like to do is to run some business rules (rules that look outside of the app or back into the database, not validation rules).  When these rules are run we'd like to return an enumerated list of validation errors.

Question:
Is there a way in ASP.Net Dynamic Data to do some sort of "Context.Validate()" before the save so we can get business rule validation errors?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The way to intercept the save depends on the Object/Relational Mapper (O/RM) you are using, LinqToSQL or Entity Framework.

If you are using LinqToSql, see this walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629301(v=vs.100).aspx

If you are using the Entity Framework, see this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can add a 'OnValidate' method to the partial class of your Linq table.  You can then perform whatever custom validation you require inside of this method, and if something fails your business rules, you can respond appropriately such as throwing a ValidationException.  This will prevent the data from being saved to the database.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(LinqClassNameMetadata))]
    public partial class LinqTableClassName
    { 
        //HERE IS THE SOLUTION
        partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action)
        {
           //Implement business rules here

           //If something is wrong, you can do something like
           throw new ValidationException("assert whatever is wrong");
        }
}

public class LinqClassNameMetadata
{
        //Just an example
        [Required]
        public object WhateverColumn;

         //etc.
}
```